# ZXing Barcode Scanner Intent: set DecodeHintType.ASSUME_GS1

Tags: android, android-intent, barcode, zxing, gs1-128

In my app I want to scan a GS1-128 barcode, and need the FNC1 characters passed from the ZXing barcode scanner.
Right now I just receive the plain text without the FNC1 characters.

Is there a way to pass the DecodeHintType.ASSUME_GS1 via Intent to the scanner app?

I don't want to include the complete scanner source in my app and rather use the Intent.

In the source code of the scanner I can see that the DecodeHintType needs to be set to achive that:
https://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/core/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/oned/Code128Reader.java

```
 boolean convertFNC1 = hints != null && hints.containsKey(DecodeHintType.ASSUME_GS1);
```

Thanks for any help.
I searched almost the whole web and didn't find an answer to this.
This is driving me nuts...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the end it turned out that it was easier than I thought:

```
intentScan.putExtra("ASSUME_GS1", true);
```

The hints can be set with extras.
I just had to figure it out, because I couldn't find it anywhere how to do that.

I downloaded the code of the Barcode Scanner and did a little debugging.
But now I can use the original app and get the barcode via Intent. :-)

Comment: Hi, do you happen to know how to achieve this in the iOS / CPP version of the zing library?

Comment: Ok, also you were scanning using intents. I have my iOS scanner running with GS1 recognition now on iOS. But in the app, not with intents....

Comment: In which file did you add that line of code? I'm trying to achieve the same for the data matrix reader and wanted to try that line there. However I can't find the intentScan variable inside the Code128Reader.java.

Comment: @MatthiasMax `intentScan` variable is your intent, which you have to create
e.g.: `Intent intentScan = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");`

Comment: I used the scanning via Intent method described here: https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Scanning-Via-Intent you can add the line withing the initiateScan method.

Comment: Another way to achieve this is `IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(yourActivity); integrator.addExtra("ASSUME_GS1", true); integrator.initiateScan();`

Comment: How can I get FNC  character from .Net library in Xamarin project?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's the hint you need. It will return FNC1 as ASCII 29. There's not a general way to pass the hints by Intent, but some are supported as additional Intent extras. If you want to submit a patch that triggers this hint I'll take a look.

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks for your help. I figured it out now (check the answer below). So it looks like there is a certain way to pass the hints. BTW great product! :-)

Comment: Hi @sean-owen I'm trying to add the ASSUME_GS1 hint to the data matrix reader with no luck. Where would I put the call inside the DataMatrixReader.java?

Comment: I'm using the official phonegap barcodescanner which includes the zxing lib. However I believe it's way out of date, is this correct? It doesn't even have the ASSUME_GS1 flag defined: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/blob/master/src/android/LibraryProject/src/com/google/zxing/DecodeHintType.java

Comment: In other words: With your maintained version of zxing it is possible the see data matrix FNC1 identifer ]d2 ? Thanks for a quick tip!