# Converting small barcode into longer

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner

Working on a Point of Sale system and trying to understand how to convert a smaller barcode to its longer registered one:

Example is for **Coca-Cola Classic, 20 Oz. Bottle** whose barcode shows as `04904403` and getting it to its correct UPC `049000000443` (https://www.upcitemdb.com/upc/49000000443)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is the UPC-E code.  You are looking to convert UPC-E code to UPC-A.

See more about Universal Product codes here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Product_Code

You can also look at this already answered question: [How to convert a UPC-E barcode to a UPC-A barcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31539005/how-to-convert-a-upc-e-barcode-to-a-upc-a-barcode)

You might also want to look at this website: https://www.taltech.com/barcodesoftware/symbologies/upc